# List of Objects in Swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, spring-boot-actuator

I need to display the model schema as a arrayList for "SourcePoints"

**Current Body for my post method in swagger:**

```
 {
  "PreferredTransforms": [
    {
      "Code": 0
    }
  ],
  "SourceCRS": {
    "Code": 50015
  },
  "SourcePoints": [
    {
      "x": "7000000",
      "y": "3100000",
      "z": "0"
    }
  ],
  "TargetCRS": {
    "Code": 50015
  }
}
```

**But i want multiple sourcePoints. ie like below structure should be available in my swagger page:**

```
{
  "PreferredTransforms": [
    {
      "Code": 0
    }
  ],
  "SourceCRS": {
    "Code": 50015
  },
  "SourcePoints": [
    {
      "x": "10000",
      "y": "20000",
      "z": "40000"
    },
 {
      "x": "40000",
      "y": "50000",
      "z": "60000"
    }
  ],
  "TargetCRS": {
    "Code": 50015
  }
}
```

**My Pojo classes Look like this**

**CRSConversionResult.java**

```
public class CRSConversionResult {

    @JsonProperty("CriteriaMessage")
    private String criteriaMessage;

    @JsonProperty("ResultPoints")
    private List<Point> resultPoints;

    @JsonProperty("TransformName")
    private String transformName;

    @JsonProperty("TransformDescription")
    private String transformDescription;

    public List<Point> getResultPoints() {
        return resultPoints;
    }}
```

**Point.java**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Point {

    @JsonProperty("x")
    private String x = "0";

    @JsonProperty("y")
    private String y = "0";

    @JsonProperty("z")
    private String z = "0";

    public Point() {

    }}
```

**build.gradle file**

```
compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.5.0")
compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.5.0")
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for the above?

Comment: Currently swagger does not support multiple items. so List is not  supported.